# Control plot-in-plot in Matlab

Tags: matlab, plot

I followed the steps for making a plot-inside-a-plot given [here](http://de.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/35245-matlab-plot-gallery-plot-in-plot/content/html/Plot_in_Plot.html), which worked very nicely. However, I would like to update something inside "the large plot", but every update that I give to the figure goes to the plot created last, i.e. the plot-within-a-plot.

How can I control which of the two plots I give commands to?

Small example:

```
% Create data
t = linspace(0,2*pi);
t(1) = eps;
y1 = sin(t);
y2 = cos(t);

% Place axes at (0.1,0.1) with width and height of 0.8
figure
handaxes1 = axes('Position', [0.12 0.12 0.8 0.8]); 

hold on
% Main plot
plot(t, y1)
xlabel('t')
ylabel('sin(t)')
set(handaxes1, 'Box', 'off')

% Adjust XY label font
handxlabel1 = get(gca, 'XLabel');
set(handxlabel1, 'FontSize', 16, 'FontWeight', 'bold')
handylabel1 = get(gca, 'ylabel');
set(handylabel1, 'FontSize', 16, 'FontWeight', 'bold')

% Place second set of axes on same plot
handaxes2 = axes('Position', [0.6 0.6 0.2 0.2]);
fill(t, y1.^2, 'g')
set(handaxes2, 'Box', 'off')
xlabel('t')
ylabel('(sin(t))^2')

%Now, I would like to return to the sine plot and add a cosine!
plot(t, y2)
```

However, this results in the plot overwriting the `fill`-command in the small plot, rather than adding the cosine in the large plot, even though I have `hold on`. I realise that I could just shift the order of plot commands, but in my current project, I would like to have the small plot all the while the larger one is being updated/animated.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I'm not 100% sure I know what you are asking, but I think this (somewhat clunky) solution will work: Replace the last line (`plot(t, y2)`) with `axes(handaxes1);plot(t, y2);axes(handaxes2);`

Comment: This works, it just took me some time to create the `axes` the right place to avoid having two axes on top of each other. Now, I just need to bring the small plot forward in the picture without activating it!

Write an answer, then I'll accept it...

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the axis you want to use in the `plot` command. For example, to force it to use your large axis:

```
plot(handaxes1, t, y2)
```

You can use the same trick with most Matlab plotting commands. For example, if you want to hold the graphics only for the large plot you can call `hold(handaxes1, 'on')`.